# How do I get my cards next to each other in html/css/js?

Tags: html, jquery, css, web, design-patterns

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="post-module">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="date">
          <div class="day">27</div>
          <div class="month">Mar</div>
        </div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169963/photo-1429043794791-eb8f26f44081.jpeg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <div class="category">Photos</div>
        <h1 class="title">City Lights in New York</h1>
        <h2 class="sub_title">The city that never sleeps.</h2>
        <p class="description">New York, the largest city in the U.S., is an architectural marvel with plenty of historic monuments, magnificent buildings and countless dazzling skyscrapers.</p>
        <div class="post-meta"><span class="timestamp"><i class="fa fa-clock-">o</i> 6 mins ago</span><span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="#"> 39 comments</a></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-module">
      <!-- Thumbnail-->
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="date">
          <div class="day">27</div>
          <div class="month">Mar</div>
        </div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169963/photo-1429043794791-eb8f26f44081.jpeg"/>
      </div>
      <!-- Post Content-->
      <div class="post-content">
        <div class="category">Photos</div>
        <h1 class="title">City Lights in New York</h1>
        <h2 class="sub_title">The city that never sleeps.</h2>
        <p class="description">New York, the largest city in the U.S., is an architectural marvel with plenty of historic monuments, magnificent buildings and countless dazzling skyscrapers.</p>
        <div class="post-meta"><span class="timestamp"><i class="fa fa-clock-">o</i> 6 mins ago</span><span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="#"> 39 comments</a></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-module">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="date">
          <div class="day">27</div>
          <div class="month">Mar</div>
        </div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/169963/photo-1429043794791-eb8f26f44081.jpeg"/>
      </div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <div class="category">Photos</div>
        <h1 class="title">City Lights in New York</h1>
        <h2 class="sub_title">The city that never sleeps.</h2>
        <p class="description">New York, the largest city in the U.S., is an architectural marvel with plenty of historic monuments, magnificent buildings and countless dazzling skyscrapers.</p>
        <div class="post-meta"><span class="timestamp"><i class="fa fa-clock-">o</i> 6 mins ago</span><span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="#"> 39 comments</a></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'proxima-nova-soft', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.post-module {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  min-width: 270px;
  height: 470px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
.post-module:hover,
.hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.post-module:hover .thumbnail img,
.hover .thumbnail img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.post-module .thumbnail {
  background: #000000;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.post-module .thumbnail .date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #e74c3c;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 12.5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.post-module .thumbnail .date .day {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.post-module .thumbnail .date .month {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-module .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 120%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
.post-module .post-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.75, 0.61, 1.05) 0s;
}
.post-module .post-content .category {
  position: absolute;
  top: -34px;
  left: 0;
  background: #e74c3c;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-module .post-content .title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.post-module .post-content .sub_title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.post-module .post-content .description {
  display: none;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
.post-module .post-content .post-meta {
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  color: #999999;
}
.post-module .post-content .post-meta .timestamp {
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}
.post-module .post-content .post-meta a {
  color: #999999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.hover .post-content .description {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.container {
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 25px;
  -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.container .column .demo-title {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.post-module').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.description').stop().animate({
      height: "toggle",
      opacity: "toggle"
    }, 300);
  });
});
```

This is the output I'm getting (my screen is too small to capture the rest of the first and bottom card):

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKnH1.png)

As you can see, all 3 cards are directly on top of each other.

I would like for them to be in the same row and next to each other. Like this:

[my desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFGmR.png)

What am I doing wrong? I tried doing float:left; and display:inline and stuff but nothing works.

Here's a codepen.io if that helps: https://codepen.io/thatrandomthinglol/pen/QWKKbQd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add property `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to .column, now the cards should be next to each other, you can add `margin: 0 (x)px` to .post-module to give some gaps between the cards.

If you want to make the cards bigger, you should remove property `width: 50%` in .column or `max-width: 50%` in .container.

[Here is an example of cards next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbBBs.png) after adding the 3 properties. As said, you can make them bigger by removing the width constraints.

Float actually also works, but you need to add the property `float-left` to .post-module rather than .column (i.e. add to the cards). And you need to make sure that the total width of the 3 cards is smaller than the width of the column, only in this way will the floated elements be displayed in one row, next to each other. Otherwise, the cards simply don't have enough space in one row and will have to be put in separate rows.

Answer (score -1):

I would not use `flex`. Try this. Change the width of `post-module` if you want other than 3 items per row.

```
.container .column {
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkti-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post-module {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 31%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 470px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
}
```

Comment: didn't work for me. is the width:31% and margin the only change? I also removed float

Comment: `display: inline-block;` This is the key change.